# Opera Dragonfly Remote Debugging: how to connect through javascript?

Tags: javascript, opera, remote-debugging

Right now i'm trying to setup remote debugging for two opera instances. The problem now is, that i can't open the "opera:debug" window to connect (it's just not possible, opera is embedded in a set-top-box and the browser is disabled).
I checked the "opera:debug" page for javascript calls. to connect to a remote debugger the page calls the function

```
    opera.connect(ip, port, callbackFnc).
```

so far so good, or not? while the "opera:debug" page can call this function, all other pages don't know the connect function on the opera object. It's only available in "opera:debug".

code so far (implemented in javascript that runs on set-top-box):

```
    if ( opera ) {
        opera.connect("192.168.1.4", "7001", function () { alert("worked"); });
    }
```

so my questions now: how can i connect to the remote debugger with javascript only? and how can it be, that the connect function is only available at the "opera:debug" page?

Answer (score 2):

As you're guessing, the opera.connect() method for connecting to a debugger is only available on the opera:debug page. If you can't open opera:debug, remote debugging is not possible I'm afraid. I guess this limited set-top-box thingy doesn't let you add user JS either? :-/

(If you open opera:debug, do you get an error page? I guess using opera.connect() from a bookmarklet on the error page won't work but you can always try..)